# JSON Syntax Error... I don't see it

Tags: javascript, json

The jsonlint site said there's something wrong on that line... I can't find it at all.
The real file is about 1000 lines so it could be a problem later in the file, but I just wanted to check on SO because I don't see any error at all.

```
{
    "Blue Tag" : {
        "Queries" : {
            "DepartmentID" : {
                "name" : "Departments",
                "params" : ["1"],
                "options": []
            },
            "ZoneID" : {
                "name" : "Zones",
                "params" : [
                    "1",
                    "Department" : { // error here for some reason
                        "ref" : "true", 
                        "returns" : "value"
                    }
                ],
                "options": []
            },
            "MachineID" : {
                "name" : "Machines",
                "params" : [
                    "1",
                    "Department" : { 
                        "ref" : true, 
                        "returns" : "value"
                    },
                    "Zone" : { 
                        "ref" : true, 
                        "returns" : "value"
                    }
                ],
                "options": []
            }
        },
        "Emails" : ["*@*.com","*@*.com"],
        "PK" : "ID",
        "Table" : "BlueTags",
        "Connection" : "Safety"
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Parse error on line 17:
...        "Department": {                
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

Comment: You can't mix an object and an array.

Comment: @SLaks well that sucks.

Comment: @SLaks What you are saying is misleading, you can, that's just no the right syntax. You can't add properties as an item in the array, which is what the OP seems to be trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"params" : [
    "1",
    "Department" : { 
        "ref" : "true", 
        "returns" : "value"
    }
]
```

This is a regular array, not an object. Change the `[]` to `{}`

```
"params" : { // <- Curly brackets denote an object consisting of key:value pairs
    "1" : "",
    "Department" : { 
        "ref" : "true", 
        "returns" : "value"
    }
}
```

or, if you want to keep the params as a numerical array

```
"params" : [ // <- Square brackets denote an array consisting values (which can be, in turn, objects)
    "1",
    {"ref" : "true", "returns" : "value"}
]
```

Comment: So you're saying you can't embed objects in arrays? That's stupid.

Comment: Yes you can but you can't add a key to this object, you'de have to ommit "Department"

Comment: @KthProg: Yes, you can, you were just doing it wrong.

Comment: @KthProg: No, of course you can: `[1, {foo: bar}]`. But you somehow mixed the syntax for objects and arrays, which doesn't work: `[1, foo: bar]`. See the difference?

Comment: @somethinghere oh okay I'll just add the names as a field of the object. thank you.

Comment: I think this is closest to what the op had: `"params" : [
    "1",
    {"Department": {"ref" : "true", "returns" : "value"}}
]`

Comment: Was going to say the sam thing as @JuanMendes. OP is just missing brackets around the object[s].

Comment: @JuanMendes This would be another level of nesting. I'de suggest to either number the whole object or omit `"Department"`

Comment: @somethinghere You shouldn't inline it, it seems the OP needs to know `Department`, look at the params under `MachineId`  `"MachineID" : {
                "name" : "Machines",
                "params" : [
                    "1",
                    "Department" : { 
                        "ref" : true, 
                        "returns" : "value"
                    },
                    "Zone" : { 
                        "ref" : true, 
                        "returns" : "value"
                    }
                ],`

Comment: The format that I went with was `[{"name" : "Department", "ref" : "true", "returns" : "value"}]` since that still allows me to iterate through the array as I need to.

Comment: Yes, that works, but what @somethinghere suggested doesn't because it loses "Department", "Zone"

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot brackets around your objects in the `params` arrays

```
"params" : [
    "1",
    {"Department" : { 
        "ref" : true, 
        "returns" : "value"
    }},
    {"Zone" : { 
        "ref" : true, 
        "returns" : "value"
    }}
],
```